# Canon network printer on Arch Linux: stuck on "Rendering completed"

Tags: arch-linux, cups, printer

I'm attempting to print via network to a Canon imageClass MF743cdw from CUPS on Arch Linux. I installed cnrdrvcups-lb from the AUR and the relevant driver was available in CUPS, but when I attempt to print I get stuck on "Rendering completed" and it never prints. I tried using CAPT to set the printer up instead, and that gave the same results. I'm afraid I might be screwed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.